# LED1 on SASEBO-W doesn't turn on

Tags: fpga

I have a *[SASEBO-W / 3-94336-3](http://satoh.cs.uec.ac.jp/SASEBO/en/board/sasebo-w.html)* board for testing side-channel attacks. I followed the steps that is mentioned in the manual for setting jumpers and switches. But after connecting USB cable and JTAG config cable, LED1 doesn't turn on on the board. Does anybody have any idea what's wrong?

Moreover when I do a right-click in *ISE iMPACT* and click on *initial chain* it pop a windows that indicated  *There are many unknown devices being detected* and the *Identify failed*.

How can I debug this board?

LED1 on the board is marked with *core* in the button.

Comment: It appears to be an FPGA board. Much more information is required.

Comment: @LeonHeller http://satoh.cs.uec.ac.jp/SASEBO/en/board/sasebo-w.html

Comment: It could be anything. Start by verifying the input voltage is correct (like with any hardware not responding as expected).

Comment: LED1 should turn on when 2.5V is present and the 1.2V regulator turns on the 'power good' pin. Check J4 for 1.2V. Does LED2 turn on?

Comment: @VladimirCravero Yes, LED2 , LED3 and LED4 are turned on.

Comment: And what about J4? Can you measure the voltage there?

Comment: @VladimirCravero `J1 = J7 = 3.04 v` , `J2= J3 = J4 = J5 = J8 = 0 v` , `J6 = 0.12 v`

Comment: The 1V2 linear regulator is probably the culript then.

Comment: @VladimirCravero The problem solved. I was forgot to open JP6. it is _FPGA core power_ jumper and it is not written in the quick started guidance document to open it. I found it in a table in the board manual and now the board works properly. Thank you. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Good. Please add your own answer so that if anybody gets stuck as you did can easily read the answer without digging in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at the SASEBO-W documents we find out that **JP6** on the board is for *FPGA Core Power* and it must be **Open** to make this LED on.(The LED1 is specified with word *Core* on the board also.)

Note that this is not mentioned in the Quick Guide manual, but you can find it in *table 21* of *Side-channel Attack Standard EvaluationBoard SASEBO-W Specification* [here](http://satoh.cs.uec.ac.jp/SASEBO/pdf/SASEBO-W_Spec_Ver1.2_English.pdf).